# Insertion Sort loop invariant

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

```
function insertionSort(arr)  {
var length = arr.length,
val,
i,
j;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    value  = arr[i];
    for(j = i - 1; j > -1 && arr[j] > value; j--) {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]
    }
    arr[j+1] = value;
}
return arr;
```

}

console.log(insertionSort([6,1,23,4,2,3]))

---

I am looking at an example of the insertion sort algorithm encoded in javascript, and having trouble understanding why it passes the conditional of the inner for loop. To be clear, this algorithm is correct -- I'm just having difficulty understanding why.

If j is initialized with i - 1, then the value of j is -1, since i is initialized at  0. In the first part of the conditional it states j > -1, which means it won't pass the this test, since j is not greater than -1.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: That need to skip the first iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the first iteration will *not* enter the second loop, but this is okay. Notice what that loop is doing. It's swapping `array[j+1]` with `array[j]`. When `i == 0`, then `j == -1`. You can't swap `array[0]` with `array[-1]`, since it doesn't exist. This is a clever way of bypassing that issue.

However, this only happens on the first iteration. Subsequent iterations will enter the loop as expected.

Comment: hmm, maybe I'm not understanding how a for loop works. my assumption was that once it fails the conditional, there are no further iterations. Ah, it just occurred to me that the outter for loop causes it to try again with different values, allowing for subsequent iterations! I  think I'm not used to seeing an inner for loop fail right out of the gate, which threw me off. Thank you very much.